# Best Anti-Mev method?

Tags: web3.js, python

I am currently working on a project which involves swapping token (raydium / jupiter) and I just wanted to know if there is any reliable methods for anti-mev, such that I can prevent sandwich attacks, etc when performing swaps.

I have found [this github project](https://github.com/Jac0xb/lighthouse//) which seems to somewhat be a step in the right direction for what Im looking for but Im not sure it will help me in my current use case.

Any information or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "anti-MEV". At a conceptual level, there's nothing you can do to stop someone from front-running or back-running your transactions, unless you're the leader proposing the block to the network.

Guard transactions (via Lighthouse or otherwise) that surround your transaction are a great option, but require that the node processes your transactions serially, which is only guaranteed on... MEV nodes.

You can also include guard *instructions* in your transaction. For example, if you're swapping tokens, and you want to make sure that you end up with at least 100 tokens, you can include a self-transfer for 100 tokens at the end of the transaction, ie:

```
spl_token::instruction::transfer(
    &spl_token::id(),
    &my_account_pubkey,
    &my_account_pubkey,
    &my_wallet_pubkey,
    &[],
    expected_amount
)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am having some trouble conceptualising how to add these guard instructions to my transactions. The context for my use case is that I have two types of transaction being done in my program. One is in python which uses solders/solana-py to do swaps using JUP. And the other is in typescript which is using the raydium swap sdk. I know it doesn't mean much to you but this issue is quite urgent to me and I would really appreciate some more insight how I could integrate guard instruction. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Transactions are made up of one or more instructions. When you do a jupiter or raydium swap, your transaction contains instructions to those programs. To add a guard to your transaction, you just need to add another instruction to check that the account has the expected amount at the end, just like what I showed. So just append another instruction to the array in your transaction, nothing else needed